# Which Microsoft Azure version?

Tags: azure

I want to use remote notifications for my Android app using Xamarin. Now I found a way implementing this through Microsoft Azure. 
So I am a student and have a Microsoft DreamSpark account. Now i thought, I could download Azure via DreamSpark, but which of these packages I need?

- Microsoft Azure Authoring Tools
- Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for .NET
- Microsoft Azure Emulator
- Microsoft Azure LightSwitch Tools for Visual Studio 2013
- Microsoft Azure Mobile SDK
- Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET 2.5
- Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator
- Microsoft Azure Storage Tools
- Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio

I don't think I need a Mobile SDK, do I?

Answer (score 3):

You have to install Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET so that you enable azure projects in your Visual Studio.

But if you only require to build a Notification Service, consider building an Azure Mobile service straight from the Azure Portal. Then you can configure your android application to use that service.

Documentation and more help can be found : 

1. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-android-get-started/

2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn629482.aspx

Answer (score 0):

what you would want to look at is 'push notification' feature of Azure mobile service / Azure Mobile app service (this is the new name). Depending on which back end you are using with Android Xamarine (.NET/JavaScript)you can find tutorials (links below). You will need an active Google account, Google Cloud Messaging Client Component, Xamarin.Android and the Azure Mobile Services Component installed in your project.

See here for more details on this, hope this helps:
[Add push notifications to your Mobile Services app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started-push/?rnd=1)
[Get started with Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started/?rnd=1)